# Unable to stop the IIS Services

Tags: windows, iis-7, mysql-workbench, iis-express

Good Day,

I have just installed MySQL workbench and try to run this but the error message is pop up **Your connection attempt is failed for user root.** When I hit the `localhost` from my browser it open up the `IIS7` page.First I have stopped the services using IIS UI but it didn't work then I have unmarked the IIS from the `Windows Turn Feature On/Off` and also gave the restart to my machine but it still ping to `IIS7`. I have also tried the alternate way which was mentioned in the already discussed thread using `cmd` type `iisretart /stop etc.` Any guidelines to stop the services of IIS without uninstalling it? Help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You are trying to solve the error for the MySQL connection? I doubt stopping IIS is the solution. It usually listens to different ports than MySQL (80, 8080 vs. 3306). Try a telnet to localhost with port 3306 (or which port you selected on installation, if it differs) and see if you get a response from MySQL or any other service.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `cmd` as administrator and then typing:

`net stop MsDepSvc`

You can also start the service by typing:

`net start MsDepSvc`

This will stop or start the Remote agent service for the Microsoft Web Deploy 2.0.

Comment: I have already mentioned above that I have unchecked the IIS from the Windows Feature on/off.

Answer (score 0):

in the same way for iis7 you can try:

net stop WAS (type Y and then press enter to also stop W3SVC)
net start W3SVC (this starts both WAS and W3SVC)